# How to glue elements into a list when using groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'C' : np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
                   'D' : np.asarray([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])})

     A   C   D
 0  foo  1   2
 1  bar  2   3
 2  foo  3   4
 3  bar  4   5
 4  foo  5   6
 5  bar  6   7
 6  foo  7   8
 7  foo  8   9
```

what I want is

```
    A   C                  D
 0 foo  [1,3,5,7,8]      [2,4,6,8,9]
 1 bar  [2,4,6]          [3,5,7]
```

I have written something myself, but it does not work. It gives me the original DataFrame back:

```
def my_func(df):
    df.apply(lambda x: list(x.values), axis=0)
    return df

df = df.groupby(['A']).apply(my_func)
print df
```

How can I achieve the functionality I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do, use `.agg()`:

```
In [15]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'C' : np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),
                   'D' : np.asarray([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])})
In [16]:

print df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: list(x))
                   C                D
A                                    
bar        [2, 4, 6]        [3, 5, 7]
foo  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]  [2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

I thought that `df.groupby('A').C.agg(list)` should work too. But apparently it won't.

If you want to use `apply` it can be done, but you will loose the column names:

```
In [35]:

print df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x.T.values)))
                             0                1                2
A                                                               
bar            [bar, bar, bar]        [2, 4, 6]        [3, 5, 7]
foo  [foo, foo, foo, foo, foo]  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]  [2, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Cast the result into `Series` is critical, otherwise you will get:

```
In [36]:

print df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: list(x.T.values))
A
bar              [[bar, bar, bar], [2, 4, 6], [3, 5, 7]]
foo    [[foo, foo, foo, foo, foo], [1, 3, 5, 7, 8], [...
dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have more than one column to aggregate actually 4.

Comment: Have you tried `df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: list(x))`

Comment: It works, thank you. It would be extra kind if you can tell me what's wrong with my little piece of innocent looking code :)

Comment: See edit, if you want to use `apply`, it can be done but you will loose the column names. Basically the `apply` function should return a `Series` of length of 3, compare the two new edits.

Comment: Seems mad that `df.groupby('A').agg(list)` doesn't work, I remember having some ~~argument~~ discussion that agg should work with lists... I think it's a bit better now.

Comment: @AndyHayden, worth a feature request? I personally think it make little sense to do such things (`agg` into lists). But it all come down to the `aggerate()` of the `SeriesGroupBy()` class, where `hasattr(list, '__iter__')` will return `True` and `hasattr(lambda x: list(x), '__iter__')` will return `False`. Probably changing the `if hasattr(func_or_funcs, '__iter__'):` line to `if (not isinstance(func_or_funcs, type))&hasattr(func_or_funcs, '__iter__')` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is

```
df = df.set_index('A')
a = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x['C'].values)
```

where `a` now looks like

```
A
bar          [2, 4, 6]
foo    [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

and you can access the elements via

```
a['bar']
Out[235]: array([2, 4, 6])
```

Comment: thank you very much. I have more than one columns apart from 'C' ,that is why I have defined my_func